# How to send custom email template while resetting the password?

Tags: email-template, forgot-your-password

I have a requirement. Once the "Reset Password" button is clicked on the user detail page, i would like to send custom email notifying that the password reset has been completed.
Please let me know where to add that custom email template and how to trigger that custom email template once i clicked on the "Reset Password" button. 
Please share your thoughts.

Comment: SFDCDeveloper does my ans helped you?

Comment: Hi Ratan, I have done voting for this idea in Idea Exchange. Thank you so much for your suggestion.

Comment: ok Cool... Hope in future release we can see this option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**At this time, it is not possible to customize/modify the template for password reset.**

http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181236&language=en_US

Currently this feature is not available in salesforce but you can vote for this idea in **IdeaExchange**

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KCKTAA4